# NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName memory leak when validating toolbar item

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-leaks, appkit

### Goal

Use NSPasteboard's `canReadObjectForClasses:options:` within a custom toolbar item's `- (void)validate` to determine the toolbar's enabled state.

### Issue

When using NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName and then calling `canReadObjectForClasses:options:` within the toolbar item's `- (void)validate` method it causes the Leak Profiler to detect leaks.

#### Stack Trace of Detected Leak

```
 0 libsystem_malloc.dylib _malloc_zone_calloc
   1 Foundation -[NSConcreteMapTable initWithKeyOptions:valueOptions:capacity:]
   2 AppKit -[_NSPasteboardTypeCache init]
   3 AppKit -[NSPasteboard _updateTypeCacheIfNeeded]
   4 AppKit -[NSPasteboard _cachedTypeNameUnion]
   5 AppKit -[NSPasteboard(NSTypeConversion) _conformingTypes]
   6 AppKit -[NSPasteboard canReadObjectForClasses:options:]
   7 testingPasteboardLeak -[TestToolbarItem validate] ~/Documents/Code/tests/testingPasteboardLeak/testingPasteboardLeak/TestToolbarItem.m:14
   8 AppKit -[NSToolbarItemViewer configureForLayoutInDisplayMode:andSizeMode:inToolbarView:]
   9 AppKit -[NSToolbarView _layoutDirtyItemViewersAndTileToolbar]
  10 AppKit -[NSToolbarView _syncItemSetAndUpdateItemViewersWithSEL:setNeedsModeConfiguration:sizeToFit:setNeedsDisplay:updateKeyLoop:]
  11 AppKit -[NSToolbarView _noteToolbarLayoutChanged]
  12 AppKit -[NSView _setWindow:]
  13 AppKit -[NSView addSubview:]
  14 AppKit -[NSThemeFrame addTitlebarSubview:]
  15 AppKit -[NSThemeFrame _showHideToolbar:resizeWindow:animate:]
  16 AppKit -[NSWindow _showToolbar:animate:]
  17 AppKit -[NSToolbar _show:animate:]
  18 CoreFoundation -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:]
  19 AppKit -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:]
  20 AppKit -[NSNib _instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:options:]
  21 AppKit -[NSNib _instantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:]
  22 AppKit -[NSStoryboard _instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:]
  23 AppKit NSApplicationMain
  24 libdyld.dylib start
```

### Example Code

Custom toolbar item's validate method:

```
- (void)validate {
    NSPasteboard *myPasteboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"TestPasteboardName"];
    BOOL isValid = [myPasteboard canReadObjectForClasses:@[[NSString class], [NSURL class]] options:nil];
}
```

WindowController which is delegate to the toolbar:

```
- (NSArray *)toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers:(NSToolbar *)aToolbar {
    return @[@"test"];
}

- (NSArray *)toolbarAllowedItemIdentifiers:(NSToolbar *)aToolbar {
    return @[@"test"];
}

- (nullable NSToolbarItem *)toolbar:(NSToolbar *)toolbar itemForItemIdentifier:(NSToolbarItemIdentifier)itemIdentifier willBeInsertedIntoToolbar:(BOOL)flag {
    TestToolbarItem *item = [[TestToolbarItem alloc] initWithItemIdentifier:itemIdentifier];
    [item setTitle:@"TestToolbar"];
    return item;
}
```

### What I've tried so far

- Use NSPasteboard [releaseGlobally](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboard/1527044-releaseglobally?language=objc) when closing the window -- leak still present.
- Wrap the pasteboard check in `@autoreleasepool` -- leak still present.
- Using `releaseGlobally` directly after the pasteboard check gets rid of the leak, but obviously also clears out the pasteboard.

### Question

Is there a way to use a private pasteboard's `canReadObjectForClasses:options:` within a custom toolbar item's validate method without causing a leak?

Comment: Do you see the leak once or repeatedly?

Comment: Repeatedly. As the custom toolbar item's validate method can (and will) be called multiple times -- causing more memory to leak each time canReadObjectForClasses:options: is called to check if there are items available on the clipboard for paste (to determine the toolbar item's validity).